# CRUD very slow with conditions, is there any other faster way?

Tags: crud, atk4

im having problem with CRUd now that i filled the database. CRUD is taking ages to show, becouse it takes condition from M:M tables.

Tables:
Table USER. has many labels (hasMany)
Table LABLE, has many users (hasMany)
Intermidiate Table  UserLabel, has two hasOne

I want to show all users from some label with CRUD like this:

MODEL USER:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Table {
    public $table ='user';
    function init(){
        parent::init(); 
        $this->addField('fbid')->mandatory('Facebook id required');
        ...

        $this->hasOne('Application');
        $this->hasMany('UserLabel');

        $this->addExpression('ratio')->set(function($model,$select){
            return $select->expr('ROUND(([f2] / [f1]) * 100,0)')
            ->setCustom('f1',$model->getElement('sends'))
            ->setCustom('f2',$model->getElement('clicked'));
        });


        $this->addHook('beforeSave',function($m){
                    $m['updated']=$m->dsql()->expr('now()');
                });
    }
```

MODEL LABEL:

```
class Model_Label extends Model_Table {
    public $table ='label';
    function init(){
        parent::init(); 

        $this->addField('name')->mandatory('Name required');
        $this->addFIeld('application_id')->refModel('Model_Application')->defaultValue($this->api->recall('app'))->system(true);

        $this->addField('active')->type('boolean')->defaultValue('true')->system(true);
        $this->addField('created')->type('timestamp')->defaultValue($this->dsql()->expr('now()'))->system(true);
        $this->addField('updated')->type('timestamp')->system(true);
        $this->hasMany('UserLabel');

        $m = $this->add("Model_UserLabel");
        $this->addExpression("users", $m->dsql()
                ->field($m->dsql()->expr("count(*)"), "all users")
                ->where("label_id", $this->getField("id"))
        );
```

MODEL USER LABEL

```
class Model_UserLabel extends Model_Table {
    public $table ='userlabel';
    function init(){
        parent::init(); 

        $this->hasOne('User');
        $this->hasOne('Label'); 
    }
}
```

CODE FOR CRUD

```
$c = $this->add('CRUD');
$c->setModel('User', array('name', 'gender','country','city'));
$c->model->addCondition('id','in',
  $this->add('Model_UserLabel')->addCondition('label_id', $_GET['l'])->dsql()->field('user_id')
);
```

Is there any better way to do this?

ps. I tested this solution, it is a lot faster but still very slow at around > 5.000 users:

```
//get all users
$records = $this->api->db->dsql()->option('distinct')->table('user')->join('userlabel.user_id')->field('user.id')->where('userlabel.label_id',$_GET['l'])->do_getAll();
foreach($records as $record){
  $users .= ','.$record['id'];
}
//create CRUD
$c = $this->add('CRUD');
$c->setModel('User', array('name', 'gender','country','city','sends','clicked','ratio'));
$c->model->addCondition("application_id", $this->api->recall('app'));
$c->model->addCondition('id','in',
    '('.$users.')'
);
```

Comment: Please see and post here what is resulting SQL you're running while opening CRUD. You can do that by setting $c->model->debug().

Comment: I guess addField('application_id')->refModel('Model_Application') is deprecated and you can use hasOne('Application') instead

Answer (score 0):

Source code express more than words, so you better add your model definition source code (maybe not full) in your question.

What should be one row in your CRUD/Grid? I guess it's not 1 user = 1 row, but 1 user_label should be one row in grid. So you should set UserLabel model as model for your grid.

And then define some additional fields in Model_UserLabel by joining them from user and/or label tables directly like this:

```
class Model_UserLabel extends SQL_Model {
    function init() {
        parent::init();

        // ...

        // fields from user table
        $join_u = $this->join('user', 'user_id');
        $join_u->addField('username'); // this adds fields in current model from joined table
        $join_u->addField('email');

        // fields from label table
        $join_l = $this->join('label', 'label_id');
        $join_l->addField('name');


    }
}
```

*Note: source code above is untested and put here only as example.*

---

**EDIT:**

Try this solution - almost the same as I wrote earlier above:

MODEL USER LABEL

```
class Model_UserLabel extends Model_Table {
    public $table ='userlabel';
    function init(){
        parent::init(); 

        $this->hasOne('User');
        $this->hasOne('Label'); 

        // join user table and add fields to this model from joined user table
        $j = $this->join('user', 'user_id');
        $j->addField('name');
        $j->addField('gender');
        $j->addField('country');
        $j->addField('city');

    }
}
```

CODE FOR CRUD

```
$m = $this->add('Model_UserLabel'); // UserLabel here not User
$m->addCondition('label_id', $_GET['l']); // and then this is simple

$c = $this->add('CRUD');
$c->setModel($m, array('name', 'gender','country','city'));
```

Try this solution and as (almost) always - code is untested.

---

**EDIT:**

Please try this version - is it working faster? That's basically your P.S. example, but you shouldn't extract all user IDs, join them and then create huge select with a lot of 'in'.
Faster result should be if you could do all with just one DB request without any additional processing of data.

```
// parameters
$app_id = $this->api->recall('app);
$label_id = $_GET['l'];

// prepare model for grid
$m = $this->add('Model_User'); // default User model
$m->_dsql()->option('distinct') // add join to userlabel table + conditions
    ->join('userlabel.user_id')
    ->where('userlabel.label_id', $label_id)
    ->where($m->getField('application_id'), $app_id);

// create CRUD and set it's model. All conditions already set on model above
$c = $this->add('CRUD');
$c->setModel($m, array('name', 'gender','country','city','sends','clicked','ratio'));
```

*NOTE: Source code above as often - untested :)*

Comment: Hey DarkSide, thanks for help again! Excatly, 1row = 1user, so basically im showing all users from some label. It worked ok, but now i tested with larger database (cca 30.000 users) and went very slow. Since i have to use a lot of M:M relations and end number of users is around 300k, speed of such queris is cruical..

Comment: SQL from debug is pretty normal: select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `name`,`gender`,`country`,`city`,`sends`,`clicked`,ROUND((`user`.`clicked` / `user`.`sends`) * 100,0) `ratio`,`id`,`created`,`updated`,`application_id` from `user` where `user`.`application_id` = "10" and `user`.`id` in (select `user_id` from `userlabel` where `userlabel`.`label_id` = "1" ) ?

Comment: I guess this sql query is problem, it would be much better to use joints i think? If i use sql like this: $this->api->db->dsql()->option('distinct')->table('user')->join('userlabel.user_id')->field('user.name,user.gender,user.id,user.country,user.city,user.sends,user.clicked')->where('userlabel.label_id',1);  - the results are very very fast. but how to create such query with models?

Comment: I added more example in my answer above

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution - to show Model_UserLabel. But its not OK, becouse i have a lot of stuff in model User.. Is there any way to fasten CRUD, maybe to change dsql of crud?

Comment: Of course you can always extend (or overwrite) ATK core classes to fit your needs. But still... this of what you really want to show in CRUD. It's not users (user records) you want to show there, but user vs. label records as far as I understood your question.

Comment: Hehe, i think extending is atm a little too big for me.. But no, i need to show users who are in certain label. Users have many extra function, which are inserted in model User (one of the reasons why i love ATK)

Comment: See new addition (second EDIT part) to my answer above. Do this work and is it faster?

Comment: This is going the right way, the only problem now is i get: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous. The query is like this: select distinct SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `name`,`gender`,`country`,`city`,`sends`,`clicked`,CONCAT(ROUND((`user`.`clicked` / `user`.`sends`) * 100,1),"","%") `ratio`,`id`,`created`,`updated`,`application_id` from `user` left join `userlabel` on `userlabel`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` where `userlabel`.`label_id` = :a and `user`.`active` = :a_2 limit 0, 15

Comment: I checked around, the problem is ratio,ID,created, but i really cant find how to change the fields to user.name, user.id,... Tried  ->field, ->table('user','u')... nothing working :(

Comment: By looking into DB_dsql class method render_field I guess adding ->table('user') should help in this line if ($table && $table!==UNDEFINED) {$field=$this->bt($table).'.'.$field;} but not sure.

Comment: yeah, tried that one, even ->table('user','u'), but also not working. If i put table in normal dsql, like this: $this->api->db->dsql()->table('user'), it is working (eg. it puts user.id etc), but with model it puts id, name etc, wich then conflicts with join table. Will try to dig some more, but looks like some bug when working with model?

Comment: btw, DarkSide, can i buy you a beer somehow? :)

Comment: yeah, I like beer, but sadly it's impossible to do here in StackOverflow :) When we come to final solution, then I would like that green thick near my answer :)

Comment: try adding ->del('fields') somewhere in that DSQL chain.

Comment: ahhh, the same :( Tried also to add public $table_alias = '_alias'; in  Model_User.. Is this a bug?